# Creating Aggregation Stage to Total Number of Open Transactions in MongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

One of the steps I'm using in my MongoDB aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$customer._id",
    "totalBalance": {
      "$sum": "$transactions.amounts.balance"
    }
  }
}
```

This is working as expected. It sums up the numerical values for `transactions.amounts.balance` and gives me the total dollar amount.

What I'd like to do in addition to this is determine how many transactions are used in determining this number (i.e., determine how many records there are for a given `customer_id` where the `transactions.amount.balance > 0`.

I've tried doing this:

```
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$customer._id",
    "totalOpenTransactions": {
      "$sum": { "$transactions.amounts.balance" : $gt: 0 }
    }
  }
}
```

The above didn't work. So I also tried using an array, like this:

```
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$customer._id",
    "totalOpenTransactions": {
      "$sum": [{ "$transactions.amounts.balance" : $gt: 0 }]
    }
  }
}
```

Also doesn't work.

Can `$sum` be used like this? Or do I need to approach this particular aggregation stage differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) inside `$sum` to do that:

```
{
  $group: {
    "_id": "$customer._id",
    "totalOpenTransactions": { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $gt: ["$transactions.amounts.balance", 0] }, then: 1, else: 0 } } }
  }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, @mickl.